# OutOfMemoryError while trying to download large file using Retrofit @Streaming annotation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I'm downloading files using retrofit client, but when there is large file (200 MB) it throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:`
I have `@Streaming` annotation also and this is my download service method

```
@Streaming
@GET("{path}")
suspend fun downloadFile(@Path("path") path: String): Response<ResponseBody>`
```

Here is invoke code snippet

```
suspend fun downloadFile(remotePath: String): FileDownloadResponse {
  try {
    val response = api.downloadFile(remotePath)
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
       FileDownloadResponse.Success(response.body()!!)
    } else {
      FileDownloadResponse.Fail()
    }
   } catch (e: Exception) {
     e.printStakTrace()
     FileDownloadResponse.Fail(throwable = e)

   }

}

val response = remoteRepositroy.downloadFile(remotePath)
val writeResult = response.body.writeResponseBodyToDisk()
```

Retrofit version = `2.6.0`

Coroutine version = `1.3.0-M1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have fixed it by changing `HttpLogingInterceptor` log level from `BODY` to `HEADERS`

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
   level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS
})
```

Seems strange bug fix, but it works

Comment: This fixed my problem, but my log file had the exception "unexpected end of stream".

Answer (score 0):

Try using download manager for downloading large files

You can find the complete sample here by @CommonsWare

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Internet/Download